# After Converting ASP.NET Identity 1.0 to 2.0, I cannot validate users in Web.API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity-2

I have an application originally written  in ASP.NET 4.52 with Identity 1.0.  It has a login routine returning a custom token via Web.API controller.  Now that I have updated the application in VStudio 2015 update 3, it is using Identity 2.0.  The login code that originally used IdentityHelper.SignIn() doesn't work.

I attempted to duplicate the login routine from the Account/login.aspx page (signinManager.PasswordSignIn()) but I cannot instantiate the signingManger since it requires HTTPContext and that doesn't seem to be present in web.api.

How can I validate an Identity 2.0 user in Web.API?

Comment: Without completing understanding the architecture of your web API it will be tough to answer your question. However I used this article as reference to integrate webAPI with asp.net Identity - http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/09/angularjs-token-authentication-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/